# Call function failing in JACOB

Tags: java, matlab, com, jacob

Am trying to call a function called "set" using COM interface
am getting the exception

`Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't map name to dispid: set`

eventhough when I try to call the function in matlab, it's working okey...

this is the function am using

```
public void setAttribute(String attribute, int value) {

    Variant[] vars = new Variant[3];
    vars[0] = new Variant("AttValue");
    vars[1] = new Variant(attribute);
    vars[2] = new Variant(value);

    signalGroup.invoke("set", vars);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: actually yes , i got it solved , and will post the solution soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void setIndexedAttribute(String attribute, Variant value) {

    Variant[] indecies = new Variant[1];
    indecies[0] = new Variant(attribute);
    setProperty(signalGroup, "AttValue", indecies, value);

}

public void setProperty(Dispatch activex, String attributeName, Variant[] indecies,
        Variant value) {
    Variant[] variants = new Variant[indecies.length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < indecies.length; i++) {
        variants[i] = indecies[i];
    }
    variants[variants.length - 1] = value;

    Dispatch.invoke(activex, attributeName, Dispatch.Put, variants,new int[variants.length]);
}
```

example to use it....

```
sg_1.setIndexedAttribute("State", new Variant(10));
```

Comment: @BigMikeW accpet answer please if it helped